# Binary XML file line webview wear

Tags: java, android, wear-os

When trying to open an application in a webview on a wear emulator, the application crashes with an error `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in com.buratinoapps.wearlinkinstall:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #12 in com.buratinoapps.wearlinkinstall:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView`

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/box_inset_layout_padding"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/inner_frame_layout_padding"
        app:layout_boxedEdges="all">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>
```

logs

```
2022-12-26 21:02:25.270 3818-3818/com.buratinoapps.wearlinkinstall E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.buratinoapps.wearlinkinstall, PID: 3818
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.buratinoapps.wearlinkinstall/com.buratinoapps.wearlinkinstall.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in com.buratinoapps.wearlinkinstall:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #12 in com.buratinoapps.wearlinkinstall:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in com.buratinoapps.wearlinkinstall:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line #12 in com.buratinoapps.wearlinkinstall:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12 in com.buratinoapps.wearlinkinstall:layout/activity_main: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:852)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:928)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:948)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1002)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:532)
        at com.buratinoapps.wearlinkinstall.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:44)
        at com.buratinoapps.wearlinkinstall.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:38)
        at com.buratinoapps.wearlinkinstall.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7998)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7651)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2022-12-26 21:02:25.272 3818-3818/com.buratinoapps.wearlinkinstall E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at android.webkit.WebViewFactory.getProvider(WebViewFactory.java:242)
        at android.webkit.WebView.getFactory(WebView.java:2576)
        at android.webkit.WebView.ensureProviderCreated(WebView.java:2570)
        at android.webkit.WebView.setOverScrollMode(WebView.java:2638)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5340)
        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5499)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:698)
        at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:56)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:413)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:355)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:337)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:324)
```

Answer (score 0):

androidx.webkit is not supported on Wear OS

https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/network-access#network-access

> However, the android.webkit APIs (including the CookieManager class) are not available. You can use cookies by reading and writing headers on requests and responses.